# Magic card has clear deformity, options?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I recently pulled a [Padeem, Consul of Innovation](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=417632) from a Kaladesh booster box, and placed it into a deck I was working on. When playtesting the deck with some friends, I noticed a card with a clear visual marker on the card on the top of my deck. When I pulled it my next turn, it was my Padeem I had recently obtained.

Its a very, very clear marker, a white oval on the backside of the card. If it was on the front, I would just live with it, but I don't want to bring these cards to a LGS event and get accused of marking my cards, or having one of my friends always know whats in my hand. The frontside of the card is completely clean.

Do I have any options here? Can I get a refund or sell this type of card to someone who collects misprints? Am I just going to have to fill in the circle, and hope its not noticeable?

[image: Clear deformity, white oval on top of card]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best option is going to be to buy sleeves for your deck, just make sure that they are completely opaque since with some sleeves you can still see a little bit of the background of the card. Sleeves will not only prevent your card from being considered marked, it will also help protect your deck from getting damaged as much. Some of the most popular brands are [Ultra-Pro](http://www.ultrapro.com/product_list.php?cPath=70_150&osCsid=957319246dbb352555d1b916f5171410), [KMC](http://kmcsleeves.com/), and [Dragon Shield](http://www.arcanetinmen.dk/products/dragon-shield-sleeves-standard-size-100-ct).

For your other ideas you can try talking to your local game shop and see if they are willing to exchange it, or Wizards of the Coast customer service, but I wouldn't expect either of them to do anything. For misprint collectors I do not believe this sort of error is the kind they look for, Starcity Games has an [article](http://www.starcitygames.com/magic/finance/25176-Misprints.html) about valuable misprints. As for filling it in yourself, unless you are an amazing artist there is no way you would be able to fill it in without it still being noticable so I wouldn't both trying that.

From the [Magic Tournament Rules](http://wpn.wizards.com/sites/wpn/files/attachements/mtg_mtr_30sep16_en.pdf)

> **3.11 Marked Cards**
>   Players are responsible for ensuring that their cards and/or card sleeves are not marked during the course of the
>   tournament. A card or sleeve is considered marked if it bears something that makes it possible to identify the card
>   without seeing its face, including (but not limited to) scratches, discoloration, and bends.
>
> If a player’s cards are sleeved, the cards must be examined while in the sleeves to determine if they are marked.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a mark on the back of the card, you could use opaque sleeves to hide the backs. This also protects your cards and can help in shuffling as well.